# How do I change table datacell background color when hovering and the link text within the datacell

Tags: html, css, html-table, yui

I currently have the following css code:

```
.tableLinks a{color:#002a5c; text-decoration: underline;}
.tableLinks:hover a{color:#fff; text-decoration: underline;background-color:#8aa7ca;}
.tableLinks:visited{color:#fff; text-decoration: underline;background-color:#8aa7ca;}
```

html table structure:

```
<td class="tablelinks">
    <div class="yui-dt-class">
         <a href="">the link</a>
    </div>
</td>
```

I am trying to style links within a table data cell with YUI datatables.

I have called the `className: 'tablelinks'` to attempt to style the hover state of the cell.

My intention is to have the full width and height of the table data cell background color changed upon the hover state and the link text to be changed to white.

I have attempt with code in different variation but cannot seem to get it correct. Any guidnance would be great!

Comment: Please post your table code as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors do not match, it is case-sensitive. You have `.tableLinks` with an uppercase "L" and `class="tablelinks"` with a lowercase "l".